# Why are my breakpoints not working in spring with IntellIJ Run Dashboard?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, breakpoints

I'm rusing Spring and when I debug with the Run Dashboard, my breakpoints are not halting (there is also no checkmark on the breakpoint circles).

When I debug "normally" (without Run Dashboard, just an Application in the Debug Window) it works and there is a checkmark in the breakpoint circles.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Try to post it on JetBrains' issue tracker - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: can you share a screenshot of your run config?

Comment: Make sure you are starting it in Debug mode. In `Console` tab you should see `connected` status, like `Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:52305', transport: 'socket'`. If problem remains, file an issue at - youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with full textual output from Console tab and [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085).

Comment: @Andrey it's started in debug mode and I see the `Connected to the target VM` log